# Implementing cdc but getting value error in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, change-data-capture

I am trying to perform CDC operation via Python. I am trying to perform union of the unchanged data (master file / base table) with the new file (delta file).

Below is the function I have written:

```
def processInputdata():
    df1 = pd.read_csv('master.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('delta.csv')
    df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['cust_id','cust_id'],how="outer",indicator=True)
    dfo=df[df['_merge']=='left_only']
    dfT =pd.merge(dfo,df2,on=['cust_id','cust_id'],how="right",indicator=True)
```

This is not working.
Below is the error message:

**ValueError: Cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column**

I am not sure if there is any simpler or better approach to perform CDC.

*Sample data :*

**Master file :**

```
   cust_id cust_name  cust_income cust_phone
0      111     a            78000       sony
1      222     b             8000        jio
2      333     c           108000     iphone
3      444     d           200000    iphoneX
4      555     e            20000    samsung
```

**Delta file :**

```
 cust_id cust_name  cust_income cust_phone
0      222     b        20000          jio
1      333     c        120000     iphoneX
2      666     f        76000      oneplus
```

**Expected output:**

```
   cust_id cust_name  cust_income cust_phone
0      111     a            78000       sony
1      222     b            20000        jio
2      333     c           120000     iphoneX
3      444     d           200000    iphoneX
4      555     e            20000    samsung
5.     666     f           76000     oneplus
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide some input data and a desired output

Comment: my bad, I have updated the question and added sample and expected output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `append` with `drop_duplicates` with `keep='last'`:

```
df = master.append(delta)\
           .drop_duplicates(subset=['cust_id','cust_phone'], keep='last')\
           .sort_values('cust_name').reset_index(drop=True)

   cust_id cust_name  cust_income cust_phone
0      111         a        78000       sony
1      222         b         8000        jio
2      333         c       108000    iphoneX
3      444         d       200000    iphoneX
4      555         e        20000    samsung
5      666         f        76000    oneplus
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
new_df=( df_master.merge(df_delta,how='outer',sort=False)
                  .drop_duplicates(['cust_name','cust_phone'],keep='last')
                  .sort_values('cust_id')
                  .reset_index(drop=True) )
print(new_df)

   cust_id cust_name  cust_income cust_phone
0      111         a        78000       sony
1      222         b        20000        jio
2      333         c       120000    iphoneX
3      444         d       200000    iphoneX
4      555         e        20000    samsung
5      666         f        76000    oneplus
```

---

or [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.concat.html):

```
new_df=(pd.concat([df_master,df_delta],sort=False)
          .drop_duplicates(['cust_name','cust_phone'],keep='last')
          .sort_values('cust_id')
          .reset_index(drop=True) )
print(new_df)

   cust_id cust_name  cust_income cust_phone
0      111         a        78000       sony
1      222         b        20000        jio
2      333         c       120000    iphoneX
3      444         d       200000    iphoneX
4      555         e        20000    samsung
5      666         f        76000    oneplus
```